# QDateTimeEdit focus to seconds

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a QDateTimeEdit widget in my dialog showing minutes and seconds in the form of *mm:ss*

When the widget get focus by clicking the up/down arrows the minutes are increased/decreased by default. Is there a way to set default focus to the seconds?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `QDateTimeEdit`, there is a method named `setCurrentSection()`.  All you have to do is to set the current selection to the seconds, like this:

```
dateTimeEdit->setCurrentSection(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection);
```

Comment: Ah, I saw it in Qt Designer, set as above but not working neither in widget preview and runtime. Only coding it the dialog constructor as you wrote works. A bug, maybe (I'm using QT 4.8.7)

Comment: I tried in the designer before and it doesn't worked for me too with Qt5.8. I think it is override after.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested.

A couple of the comments state the solution (`dateTimeEdit->setCurrentSection(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection);`) "does not work".

If you use this code as-is *immediately after creating a `QDateTimeEdit`* it fails to present the user with the desired section selected.  It appears the Qt internals *reset* the selection (to the first section) at some point after initially showing the widget.  I did not bother to delve into the source code to discover precisely where.  But the following two samples show how to "workaround" this.

If you do *not* want to subclass `QDateTimeEdit` I had to do this:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, [timeEdit]() { timeEdit->setSelectedSection(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection); });
```

It works, and you can see the selection move from the first section when it is initially shown to the seconds when the timer fires. Note that the time delay size seems to be critical here. I tried with `0` and even with `100` and it did not work. For me, I needed `1000` (1 second) before it worked!  My 1 second was on a standalone program which had to start up. You will need to play with that figure depending on your machine and where you call it/show the widget.

If you want "better performance" and are prepared to subclass so as to override `showEvent()`, I found (I am using `QTimeEdit`, but same for `QDateTimeEdit`):

```
class MyTimeEdit : public QTimeEdit
{
public:
    explicit MyTimeEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QTimeEdit(parent)
    {
    }
    explicit MyTimeEdit(const QTime &time, QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QTimeEdit(time, parent)
    {
    }
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event) override
    {
        QTimeEdit::showEvent(event);
        // next line commented out because still does not work
//        this->setSelectedSection(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection);
        // next line still requires `100` delay on my machine, but better than `1000`
        QTimer::singleShot(100, [this]() { this->setSelectedSection(QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection); });
    }
};
```

Still needed to use a time delay, but getting that down to `100` makes it so the user does not see the selection start and then move.

Answer (score 0):

You need override `focusInEvent`().

For example:

```
focusInEvent(QFocusEvent * event){
    QTimeEdit::focusInEvent( event );
    switch (event->reason()) 
    {
    case Qt::BacktabFocusReason:
    case Qt::ShortcutFocusReason:
    case Qt::TabFocusReason:
        setSelectedSection( SecondSection ); break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```